# Show that a group of order $28$ is solvable

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $28 = 2^2 \cdot 7$.  Show that $G$ is solvable.

It is easy to show that $G$ is not simple, since it contains a unique Sylow $7$-subgroup.  Since this is a $p$-subgroup, it is cyclic, hence normal in $G$, then I can make my composition series in the following way:

$\{e\}$ is normal in $P_7$ is normal in $G$

Is this enough?  It seems like I am missing something important.

Comment: You're okay because $[G:P_7]=4$ and the only groups with order $4$ are both Abelian. Similarly, the only group of order $7$ is abelian.

Comment: It's instant from Burnside's theorem, of course.

Comment: The comment by @Ravi is enough to finish the proof of solvability, but if you intend to exhibit a composition series then one more step is needed. In a composition series, each group is supposed to be a **maximal** normal subgroup of the next, so the step from $P_7$ to $G$ should be broken into two steps.  $P_7$ has index $2$ in a group $H$, which in turn has index $2$ in $G$.